# How do I convert YAML to XML in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, yaml

Are there any modules in CPAN to convert YAML lists to well formed XML?

From YAML:

```
- fruits: 
  - apple
  - pear
  - orange
```

To XML:

```
<fruits>
  <apple />
  <pear />
  <orange />
</fruits>
```

Comment: The best idea would probably be to read in your data using a YAML parser, and output it with an XML formatter. I would recommend that you check out XML::Simple.

Comment: @Csongor Fagwal I've though of doing that. I'm just afraid that instead of doing the task at hand I'l end up writing yet another CPAN module. Anyway as a Perl programmer, laziness is a virtue. So says Larry. A CPAN module would be ideal.;-)

Comment: I think you can map a YAML document to an XML document in multiple ways, so joining a YAML parser with an XML creator is basically what you want to do. It's actually two lines of code. It doesn't really make sense to create a YAML-to-XML converter module, IMHO. It's like creating a separate PNG to JPG converter, a PNG to GIF converter, etc. instead of just using ImageMagick :)

Comment: I've recently answered a bit similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586194/create-and-populate-complex-xml-with-perl-script/13595961#13595961

Comment: @Csongor, OP: See Ashley's solution below.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strictures;
use YAML "Load";
use XML::Simple "XMLout";

my $data = Load(do{ local $/; <DATA> });
print XMLout( $data, XMLDecl => 1 );

__DATA__
---
- fruits:
    - apple
    - pear
    - orange
```

There *might* be a combination of options for `XMLout` that will DWYW and you may need to jigger your data structure to get the root name you want, etc. You'll note from the dizzying array of options that serializing and marshalling XML to other data formats is decidedly not simple. Reading: [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) and [YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML).

Answer (score 1):

No there is no CPAN module for that. there are [CPAN modules to read YAML](https://www.metacpan.org/module/YAML) and there are [modules to write XML](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple). The data transfer will be perl data structure.

The question is what schema your XML should be in, and there are many different XML modules, so there is also no one perfect answer.

Comment: True, there is no one perfect answer -- but, there is a working example available here (see above).

Answer (score 0):

CPAN can help you with [Util::XML_YAML_PERL](http://search.cpan.org/~rchandram/Util-XML_YAML_Perl-1.0.0/lib/Util/XML_YAML_Perl.pm).

```
use Util::XML_YAML_Perl;

my $obj = Util::XML_YAML_PERL->new();

my $yaml_text = <<UNTIL_HERE;
- fruits: 
  - apple
  - pear
  - orange
UNTIL_HERE

print $obj->yaml_to_xml( $yaml_text );

# <fruits>
#  <apple />
#  <pear />
#  <orange />
# </fruits>
```

Note: This module has a glitch its documentation, and could use a patch: Util::XML_YAML_Perl is the correct package, not 'XML::YAML_PERL' as in its pod documentation.