# Create and populate complex XML with Perl script

Tags: xml, perl

I have following XML file template that I want to create and populate with Perl script. All the values of XML attributes are coming from SQL database by different queries. My XML contain few collection type of attributes.

I'm finding it difficult that which perl module should I use because there are a lot of alternatives available on CPAN.
Also, I want to know how should I approach to this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

`

```
<TumorDetails>
    <personUpi>String</personUpi>
    <ageAtDiagnosis>3.14159E0</ageAtDiagnosis>
    <biopsyPathologyReportSummary>String</biopsyPathologyReportSummary>
    <primarySiteCollection>
        <tissueSite>
            <description>String</description>
            <name>String</name>
        </tissueSite>
    </primarySiteCollection>
    <distantMetastasisSite>
        <description>String</description>
        <name>String</name>
    </distantMetastasisSite>
    <siteGroup>
        <description>String</description>
        <name>String</name>
    </siteGroup>
    <tmStaging>
        <clinicalDescriptor>String</clinicalDescriptor>
        <clinicalMStage>String</clinicalMStage>
        <siteGroupEdition5>
            <description>String</description>
            <name>String</name>
        </siteGroupEdition5>
        <siteGroupEdition6>
            <description>String</description>
            <name>String</name>
        </siteGroupEdition6>
    </tmStaging>
    <pediatricStaging>
        <doneBy>String</doneBy>
        <group>String</group>
    </pediatricStaging>
    <histologicTypeCollection>
        <histologicType>
            <description>String</description>
            <system>String</system>
            <value>String</value>
        </histologicType>
    </histologicTypeCollection>
    <histologicGradeCollection>
        <histologicGrade>
            <gradeOrDifferentiation>String</gradeOrDifferentiation>
        </histologicGrade>
    </histologicGradeCollection>
    <familyHistoryCollection>
        <familyHistory>
            <otherCancerDiagnosed>String</otherCancerDiagnosed>
            <sameCancerDiagnosed>String</sameCancerDiagnosed>
        </familyHistory>
    </familyHistoryCollection>
    <comorbidityOrComplicationCollection>
        <comorbidityOrComplication>
            <value>String</value>
        </comorbidityOrComplication>
    </comorbidityOrComplicationCollection>
    <tumorBiomarkerTest>
        <her2NeuDerived>String</her2NeuDerived>
        <her2NeuFish>String</her2NeuFish>
    </tumorBiomarkerTest>
    <patientHistoryCollection>
        <patientHistory>
            <cancerSite>String</cancerSite>
            <sequence>2147483647</sequence>
        </patientHistory>
    </patientHistoryCollection>
    <tumorHistory>
        <cancerStatus>String</cancerStatus>
        <cancerStatusFollowUpDate>1967-08-13</cancerStatusFollowUpDate>
        <cancerStatusFollowUpType>String</cancerStatusFollowUpType>
        <qualityOfSurvival>String</qualityOfSurvival>
    </tumorHistory>
    <placeOfDiagnosis>
        <initials>String</initials>
    </placeOfDiagnosis>
    <followUp>
        <dateFollowUpChanged>String</dateFollowUpChanged>
        <dateOfLastCancerStatus>1967-08-13</dateOfLastCancerStatus>
        <nextFollowUpHospital>
            <initials>String</initials>
        </nextFollowUpHospital>
        <lastFollowUpHospital>
            <initials>String</initials>
        </lastFollowUpHospital>
        <tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest>
            <her2NeuDerived>String</her2NeuDerived>
            <her2NeuFish>String</her2NeuFish>
        </tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest>
    </followUp>
</TumorDetails>
```

`

Comment: Have a look at [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the very, very important concept: there is no such thing as "XML template"! The whole point of using XML is being capable to read/write data according to some *schema*.
If you have a (consistent) XML sample but no schema definition (XSD), use [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to figure it out:

```
java -jar trang.jar sample.xml sample.xsd
```

For provided sample, the generated XSD file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="TumorDetails">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="personUpi"/>
        <xs:element ref="ageAtDiagnosis"/>
        <xs:element ref="biopsyPathologyReportSummary"/>
        <xs:element ref="primarySiteCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="distantMetastasisSite"/>
        <xs:element ref="siteGroup"/>
        <xs:element ref="tmStaging"/>
        <xs:element ref="pediatricStaging"/>
        <xs:element ref="histologicTypeCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="histologicGradeCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="familyHistoryCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="comorbidityOrComplicationCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="tumorBiomarkerTest"/>
        <xs:element ref="patientHistoryCollection"/>
        <xs:element ref="tumorHistory"/>
        <xs:element ref="placeOfDiagnosis"/>
        <xs:element ref="followUp"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
...
</xs:schema>
```

And now, the best part, called [XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCompile).
It takes your XSD schema, compiles it and fits/validates native Perl structures, producing XML as an output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Compile::Schema;

my $node = {
    personUpi                    => 'String',
    ageAtDiagnosis               => '3.14159E0',
    biopsyPathologyReportSummary => 'String',
    primarySiteCollection        => {
        tissueSite => {
            description => 'String',
            name        => 'String',
        },
    },
    ...
};

my $schema = XML::Compile::Schema->new('sample.xsd');
my $writer = $schema->compile(WRITER => 'TumorDetails');
my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(q(1.0), q(UTF-8));

print $writer->($doc, $node)->toString;
```

Comment: I found this tutorial which provides a working example:
http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_e_lozier/2011/10/using-xmlcompile-to-output-xsd-compliant-xml.html

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on what you are already familiar with. If you are comfortable navigating XML documents using the Document Object Model then [`XML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aDOM), [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) are nice, while [`XML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) is a similar module that has its own API, and you will discover whether it suits you only by trying it.

However, all these modules are intended promarily for navigating and accessing existing XML data, and they are only partially useful for creating new XML from scratch. Instead, the modules
[`XML::Generator`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aGenerator),
[`XML::Writer`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aWriter) and
[`XML::API`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aAPI)
are designed specifically for this purpose, and all have similar interfaces. My preference, and my recommendation to you, is `XML::API`, which has the most flexible interface and should suit your purpose well.

Using `XML::API`, the code to generate a given XML document has a one-to-one correspondence with the resultant XML. Each statement corresponds to a single XML element or tag, and the tag and attrbute names and text values can be derived run time, for instance using information from a database.

This program recreates your sample XML. Note that the subsections could be coded separately and parcelled up into subroutines, passing the `XML::API` object to each of them. It is also possible to generate the XML in a non-linear fashion, as each method returns a reference to the element is creates, and there is a `_goto` method which takes such a reference and sets the location of subsequent additions. Indeed, the `_close` method, rather than writing any data, just executes a `_goto` to the parent of the current element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::API;

my $xml = XML::API->new(doctype => 'xhtml');

$xml->_open('TumorDetails');

  $xml->_element('personUpi', 'String');
  $xml->_element('ageAtDiagnosis', '3.14159E0');
  $xml->_element('biopsyPathologyReportSummary', 'String');

  $xml->_open('primarySiteCollection');
    $xml->_open('tissueSite');
      $xml->_element('description', 'String');
      $xml->_element('name', 'String');
    $xml->_close('tissueSite');
  $xml->_close('primarySiteCollection');

  $xml->_open('distantMetastasisSite');
    $xml->_element('description', 'String');
    $xml->_element('name', 'String');
  $xml->_close('distantMetastasisSite');

  $xml->_open('siteGroup');
    $xml->_element('description', 'String');
    $xml->_element('name', 'String');
  $xml->_close('siteGroup');

  $xml->_open('tmStaging');
    $xml->_element('clinicalDescriptor', 'String');
    $xml->_element('clinicalMStage', 'String');
    $xml->_open('siteGroupEdition5');
      $xml->_element('description', 'String');
      $xml->_element('name', 'String');
    $xml->_close('siteGroupEdition5');
    $xml->_open('siteGroupEdition6');
      $xml->_element('description', 'String');
      $xml->_element('name', 'String');
    $xml->_close('siteGroupEdition6');
  $xml->_close('tmStaging');

  $xml->_open('pediatricStaging');
    $xml->_element('doneBy', 'String');
    $xml->_element('group', 'String');
  $xml->_close('pediatricStaging');

  $xml->_open('histologicTypeCollection');
    $xml->_open('histologicType');
      $xml->_element('description', 'String');
      $xml->_element('system', 'String');
      $xml->_element('value', 'String');
    $xml->_close('histologicType');
  $xml->_close('histologicTypeCollection');

  $xml->_open('histologicGradeCollection');
    $xml->_open('histologicGrade');
      $xml->_element('gradeOrDifferentiation', 'String');
    $xml->_close('histologicGrade');
  $xml->_close('histologicGradeCollection');

  $xml->_open('familyHistoryCollection');
    $xml->_open('familyHistory');
      $xml->_element('otherCancerDiagnosed', 'String');
      $xml->_element('sameCancerDiagnosed', 'String');
    $xml->_close('familyHistory');
  $xml->_close('familyHistoryCollection');

  $xml->_open('comorbidityOrComplicationCollection');
    $xml->_open('comorbidityOrComplication');
      $xml->_element('value', 'String');
    $xml->_close('comorbidityOrComplication');
  $xml->_close('comorbidityOrComplicationCollection');

  $xml->_open('tumorBiomarkerTest');
    $xml->_element('her2NeuDerived', 'String');
    $xml->_element('her2NeuFish', 'String');
  $xml->_close('tumorBiomarkerTest');

  $xml->_open('patientHistoryCollection');
    $xml->_open('patientHistory');
      $xml->_element('cancerSite', 'String');
      $xml->_element('sequence', '2147483647');
    $xml->_close('patientHistory');
  $xml->_close('patientHistoryCollection');

  $xml->_open('tumorHistory');
    $xml->_element('cancerStatus', 'String');
    $xml->_element('cancerStatusFollowUpDate', '1967-08-13');
    $xml->_element('cancerStatusFollowUpType', 'String');
    $xml->_element('qualityOfSurvival', 'String');
  $xml->_close('tumorHistory');

  $xml->_open('placeOfDiagnosis');
    $xml->_element('initials', 'String');
  $xml->_close('placeOfDiagnosis');

  $xml->_open('followUp');
    $xml->_element('dateFollowUpChanged', 'String');
    $xml->_element('dateOfLastCancerStatus', '1967-08-13');
    $xml->_open('nextFollowUpHospital');
      $xml->_element('initials', 'String');
    $xml->_close('nextFollowUpHospital');
    $xml->_open('lastFollowUpHospital');
      $xml->_element('initials', 'String');
    $xml->_close('lastFollowUpHospital');
    $xml->_open('tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest');
      $xml->_element('her2NeuDerived', 'String');
      $xml->_element('her2NeuFish', 'String');
    $xml->_close('tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest');
  $xml->_close('followUp');

$xml->_close('TumorDetails');

print $xml;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data will always be identical then ddoxey's TemplateToolkit solution is a good one, however, if some of the tags are sometimes not present then you'll need to build up the XML from scratch each time.

I've recently done some work with XML and was very happy with [`XML::Writer`](http://search.cpan.org/~josephw/XML-Writer-0.615/Writer.pm).

Comment: FYI, TT does include a rich interface for supporting conditionals and iteration if the situation calls for it.

Comment: I solved my problem with the same module. Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat partial to the Template toolkit.
See:

- http://metacpan.org/pod/Template
- [http://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual](http://metacpan.org/pod/Template%3a%3aManual)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;

my $tmpl = get_template();
my $rec  = get_record();
my $xml;

my $template = Template->new();

$template->process( \$tmpl, $rec, \$xml )
    || die $template->error();

print "$xml";

# ...

sub get_record {

    return {
        personUpi                    => 'String',
        ageAtDiagnosis               => '3.14159E0',
        biopsyPathologyReportSummary => 'String',
        primarySiteCollection        => {
            tissueSite => {
                description => 'String',
                name        => 'String',
            },
        },
        distantMetastasisSite => {
            description => 'String',
            name        => 'String',
        },
        siteGroup => {
            description => 'String',
            name        => 'String',
        },
        tmStaging => {
            clinicalDescriptor => 'String',
            clinicalMStage     => 'String',
            siteGroupEdition5  => {
                description => 'String',
                name        => 'String',
            },
            siteGroupEdition6 => {
                description => 'String',
                name        => 'String',
            },
        },
        pediatricStaging => {
            doneBy => 'String',
            group  => 'String',
        },
        histologicTypeCollection => {
            histologicType => {
                description => 'String',
                system      => 'String',
                value       => 'String',
            },
        },
        histologicGradeCollection => {
            histologicGrade => { gradeOrDifferentiation => 'String', }, },
        familyHistoryCollection => {
            familyHistory => {
                otherCancerDiagnosed => 'String',
                sameCancerDiagnosed  => 'String',
            },
        },
        comorbidityOrComplicationCollection => {
            comorbidityOrComplicationCollection => { value => 'String', },
        },
        tumorBiomarkerTest => {
            her2NeuDerived => 'String',
            her2NeuFish    => 'String',
        },
        patientHistoryCollection => {
            patientHistory => {
                cancerSite => 'String',
                sequence   => '2147483647',
            },
        },
        tumorHistory => {
            cancerStatus             => 'String',
            cancerStatusFollowUpDate => '1967-08-13',
            cancerStatusFollowUpType => 'String',
            qualityOfSurvival        => 'String',
        },
        placeOfDiagnosis => { initials => 'String', },
        followUp         => {
            dateFollowUpChanged        => 'String',
            dateOfLastCancerStatus     => '1967-08-13',
            nextFollowUpHospital       => { initials => 'String', },
            lastFollowUpHospital       => { initials => 'String', },
            tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest => {
                her2NeuDerived => 'String',
                her2NeuFish    => 'String',
            },
        },
    };
}

sub get_template {

    return <<'END_TEMPL';
<TumorDetails>
    <personUpi>[% personUpi %]</personUpi>
    <ageAtDiagnosis>[% ageAtDiagnosis %]</ageAtDiagnosis>
    <biopsyPathologyReportSummary>[% biopsyPathologyReportSummary %]</biopsyPathologyReportSummary>
    <primarySiteCollection>
        <tissueSite>
            <description>[% primarySiteCollection.tissueSite.description %]</description>
            <name>[% primarySiteCollection.tissueSite.name %]</name>
        </tissueSite>
    </primarySiteCollection>
    <distantMetastasisSite>
        <description>[% distantMetastasisSite.description %]</description>
        <name>[% distantMetastasisSite.name %]</name>
    </distantMetastasisSite>
    <siteGroup>
        <description>[% siteGroup.description %]</description>
        <name>[% siteGroup.name %]</name>
    </siteGroup>
    <tmStaging>
        <clinicalDescriptor>[% tmStaging.clinicalDescriptor %]</clinicalDescriptor>
        <clinicalMStage>[% tmStaging.clinicalMStage %]</clinicalMStage>
        <siteGroupEdition5>
            <description>[% tmStaging.siteGroupEdition5.description %]</description>
            <name>[% tmStaging.siteGroupEdition5.name %]</name>
        </siteGroupEdition5>
        <siteGroupEdition6>
            <description>[% tmStaging.siteGroupEdition6.description %]</description>
            <name>[% tmStaging.siteGroupEdition6.name %]</name>
        </siteGroupEdition6>
    </tmStaging>
    <pediatricStaging>
        <doneBy>[% pediatricStaging.doneBy %]</doneBy>
        <group>[% pediatricStaging.group %]</group>
    </pediatricStaging>
    <histologicTypeCollection>
        <histologicType>
            <description>[% histologicTypeCollection.histologicType.description %]</description>
            <system>[% histologicTypeCollection.histologicType.system %]</system>
            <value>[% histologicTypeCollection.histologicType.value %]</value>
        </histologicType>
    </histologicTypeCollection>
    <histologicGradeCollection>
        <histologicGrade>
            <gradeOrDifferentiation>[% histologicGradeCollection.histologicGrade.gradeOrDifferentiation %]</gradeOrDifferentiation>
        </histologicGrade>
    </histologicGradeCollection>
    <familyHistoryCollection>
        <familyHistory>
            <otherCancerDiagnosed>[% familyHistoryCollection.familyHistory.otherCancerDiagnosed %]</otherCancerDiagnosed>
            <sameCancerDiagnosed>[% familyHistoryCollection.familyHistory.sameCancerDiagnosed %]</sameCancerDiagnosed>
        </familyHistory>
    </familyHistoryCollection>
    <comorbidityOrComplicationCollection>
        <comorbidityOrComplication>
            <value>[% comorbidityOrComplicationCollection.comorbidityOrComplicationCollection.value %]</value>
        </comorbidityOrComplication>
    </comorbidityOrComplicationCollection>
    <tumorBiomarkerTest>
        <her2NeuDerived>[% tumorBiomarkerTest.her2NeuDerived %]</her2NeuDerived>
        <her2NeuFish>[% tumorBiomarkerTest.her2NeuFish %]</her2NeuFish>
    </tumorBiomarkerTest>
    <patientHistoryCollection>
        <patientHistory>
            <cancerSite>[% patientHistoryCollection.patientHistory.cancerSite %]</cancerSite>
            <sequence>[% patientHistoryCollection.patientHistory.sequence %]</sequence>
        </patientHistory>
    </patientHistoryCollection>
    <tumorHistory>
        <cancerStatus>[% tumorHistory.cancerStatus %]</cancerStatus>
        <cancerStatusFollowUpDate>[% tumorHistory.cancerStatusFollowUpDate %]</cancerStatusFollowUpDate>
        <cancerStatusFollowUpType>[% tumorHistory.cancerStatusFollowUpType %]</cancerStatusFollowUpType>
        <qualityOfSurvival>[% tumorHistory.qualityOfSurvival %]</qualityOfSurvival>
    </tumorHistory>
    <placeOfDiagnosis>
        <initials>[% placeOfDiagnosis.initials %]</initials>
    </placeOfDiagnosis>
    <followUp>
        <dateFollowUpChanged>[% followUp.dateFollowUpChanged %]</dateFollowUpChanged>
        <dateOfLastCancerStatus>[% followUp.dateOfLastCancerStatus %]</dateOfLastCancerStatus>
        <nextFollowUpHospital>
            <initials>[% followUp.nextFollowUpHospital.initials %]</initials>
        </nextFollowUpHospital>
        <lastFollowUpHospital>
            <initials>[% followUp.nextFollowUpHospital.initials %]</initials>
        </lastFollowUpHospital>
        <tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest>
            <her2NeuDerived>[% followUp.tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest.her2NeuDerived %]</her2NeuDerived>
            <her2NeuFish>[% followUp.tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest.her2NeuFish %]</her2NeuFish>
        </tumorFollowUpBiomarkerTest>
    </followUp>
</TumorDetails>
END_TEMPL
}

__END__
```

Comment: It seems that this approach is unnecessarily long because every node name has to be written at least twice - once in the record and once or more in the template.

Comment: Indeed the template is just as verbose as the document it will produce. This approach does offer the complete separation of application logic from presentation. Depending on the needs of the organization, this implementation could allow for expressing the data in any number of other formats without refactoring the application, but rather just supplying a different template.